# Button passes from one table to the other

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have been searching for this question that I am almost 100% positive has been asked before, but I can't find a link. Please provide me with a link if so and I am sorry if it's redundant, but if I  am wrong, here's what I am trying to do..

I have a table full of objects. I have a description, a price, an image, and a button in every cell. The button is just a simple "add to cart" button that will take the objects and put them into a new table (just like ordering anything online.. add to cart and then it's in your cart). My biggest problem right now is figuring a way to click the button, get the row index of those objects, and then putting them into a new table (in fact, I haven't even created the table or anything like that yet... I just want to be able to get a list of the items to fill that table.. I am trying to take it one step at a time). Here is the table code:

```
Food listOfGroceries;

    public GroceryTableSource(Food listOfGroceries)
    {
        this.listOfGroceries = listOfGroceries;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = (GroceryTableCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell_id", indexPath);
        var CurrentItem = listOfGroceries[indexPath.Row];
        cell.UpdateCell(CurrentItem);
        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return FoodList.Count;
    }

}
```

Here is the table cell:
    public partial class GroceryTableCell : UITableViewCell
    {

```
    public GroceryTableCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    internal void UpdateCell(FoodStruct currentItem)
    {
        double Price = 9.99;
        ItemDescription.Text = currentItem.FoodDescription;
        ItemPrice.Text = Price.ToString();
    }
    protected void AddToCartClicked ( UIButton sender)
    {
        YourGroceryCart(sender);
    }

    protected string YourGroceryCart(UIButton sender)
    {

    }
}
```

I cannot figure out getting the row index and I've been working on it for a few hours. I can easily access the row index when I am in the UITableViewSource class, specifically in the method GetCell, but I can't put the method I want to use in that because I need someone to click the button first!

Comment: when you create the button, store the index value in it's Tag property

Comment: I am using storyboard.. I see the Tag property and it's set to 0. How should it be set? Is it possible to set it to the indexPath.Row of the currentitem?

Comment: do it in GetCell

Comment: Is there an example you can point me to? And should I delete the button from the storyboard so I create a new button for every cell?

Comment: you will need to use the debugger to examine the GroceryTableCell object that is built in GetCell and determine how to access the Button and it's properties